# Duda con linea de un código de ensamblador

Tags: ensamblador

Buenas tengo el código siguiente de ensamblador, y soy principiante y para efectos debo de realizar el código a mano linea por linea pero no me queda claro que es lo que hace **SHL AX,02** para ese momento se que AX vale C8FE(1100 1000 1111 1110), mi duda es mas que nada por el 02 creo que también he visto con 01. Gracias de ante mano

```
MOV CX,2
MOV AX,123FH
MOV BX, 5825H 
E1: SHL AX,2
SAL BX,1            
SAR  BX,1 
SAL AX,1           
RCR AX,2
RCL BX,1
NOT AX
LOOP E1
JC  E2
JNC E
E: MOV CX,2
E2: INC BX
LOOP E2

E3: INC  AX
E4: INC  BX
SHL   AX,02
ADD   AX,1
SAR   BX,02
NOT AX
AND AH,11111110B
XOR AX,BX
OR  BH,AH
NEG AX
```

Answer (score 3):

`SHL` hace un desplazamiento a izquierda del primer operando la cantidad de bits que indique el segundo:

```
> ax = 1100 1000 1111 1110

SHL AX,02 

> ax = 0010 0011 1111 1000
```

También corresponde decir que la operación se corresponde con la multiplicación aritmetica de `AX` * `2^(cantidad de bits)`